# UITableview cell retain custom image view filter

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

I often faces this issue when developing tableview custom cell.

Here is problem, I have a tableview and it has lots of customized cell (a UIImageView and UILabel) When user tap any of this cell pushes new UIViewController and user filling some data and tapped the "Save" viewcontroller push back with delegation method.

In this delegate method I inspect tapped cell and change that tint color (like selected state but I'm only changing custom imageview tint color). So this changes correctly but when I'm scrolling any vertical direction tint color disappear. Below pictures and code for figuring out correctly.

**When pop to view controller from delegate method (works correctly)**

[image]

**When scrolling vertical direction tin**

[image]

```
// Custom cell

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@property(strong, nonatomic) UILabel *titleLabel;
@end

// Custom Cell implementation nothing special here.

// UIViewController delegate method when pop back
// I'm filling specific color 

@interface UIViewController
@property (strong,nonatomic) CustomCell *myCustomCell;
@end

@implementation UIViewController



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...

    _myCustomCell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ...
}

- (void)userTappedBackButton {
    _myCustomCell.imageView.image = [cell.customImageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    _myCustomCell.imageView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.27 green:0.58 blue:0.98 alpha:1];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the index path of the tapped cell when it is selected rather than the cell itself, which is reused as you scroll. Apply the selected styling in cellForRow when you're presenting the cell for the matching "selected" index path, in addition to when you return back to the view

**Update**: adding code to clarify

In your custom cell, provide simple ways to enable/disable the tint:

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property(strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@property(strong, nonatomic) UILabel *titleLabel;

- (void)enableLastSelectedHighlight;
- (void)disableLastSelectedHighlight;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation CustomCell

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    // Reset prior to being reused
    [self disableLastSelectedHighlight];
}

- (void)enableLastSelectedHighlight
{
    self.imageView.image = [cell.customImageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    self.imageView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.27 green:0.58 blue:0.98 alpha:1];
}

- (void)disableLastSelectedHighlight;
{
    self.imageView.image = [cell.customImageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}

@end
```

In your TableViewController.m file, keep track of the selection, either via `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, or your existing custom delegate `userTappedBackButton`. The implementation of the will be the same:

```
@interface MyTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *lastSelectedCellIndexPath;

@end

@implementation MyTableViewController

// Your existing implementation
// ...

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Update our reference to the tinted row
    [self setLastSelectedCellIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Un-tint any currently tinted cells
    [self.tableView.visibleCells makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(disableLastSelectedHighlight)];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Get your cell
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPath == self.lastSelectedCellIndexPath) {
        // This cell should be tinted
        [cell enableLastSelectedHighlight];
    }
    // The rest of your cell setup...
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks dude. That's what i need. But another approach is the lazly load for all cell. But sometimes it makes trouble.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why, and what solution you end up with

Comment: When i tapped same cell again and again my array became like this <item1, item2, item1, item2,item1,item1> I think this is not "convenient" way to this for sake of application performance.

Comment: Added code sample to make it clearer. Sounds like you're storing it as an array - no need unless multiple will be tinted. Then you could check if the index path is already a member of your "tinted index paths" array before re-adding. Or us NSSet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you are saving a reference to the `UITableViewCell` but the cells are being reused.

You need to save the information about the cell to be highlighted in another manner, that cannot be influenced by the cells being reused. I would suggest by using the `indexPath`.

Something like the following should work:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *lastSelectedIndexPath;


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([indexPath isEqual:self.lastSelectedIndexPath]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [cell.customImageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        cell.imageView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.27 green:0.58 blue:0.98 alpha:1];
    }
    ...
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Save the selected indexPath
    self.selectedIndexPath =  indexPath;
}
- (void)userTappedBackButton {
    // Reload the row that needs to be updated with the new tint color
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Let me know if it worked out.

Comment: I have more than one section so i guess this code won't work.

Comment: You are saving the indexPath which has both section and row information, so it will work with more sections for sure